# Combinar dos data.frames con merge permitiendo un pequeño error

Tags: r

En R existe la opción de combinar dos data.frame con *Merge()* pero si se indica en los atributos *by* las columnas por las que se desea que se combinen solamente lo hará si los datos son iguales.

¿Habría alguna forma de que se combinen con un error permitido?

Ejemplo:

Data.frame A

```
Usuarios Distancia ..........
1          20.005
2          21.000
3          23.000
4          19.009
```

Data.frame B

```
Usuarios Distancia ..........
5          20.006
6          21.000
7          23.000
8          19.008
```

Con estos datos me gustaría que se uniesen solamente si las distancias son las mismas o si tienen un error permitido <= a 0.001, por lo que el Usuario 1 y 5 tendrían que combinarse al igual que el 4 y 8 y no solamente el 2 y 6 y el 3 y 7.

Comment: Por favor utiliza el comando `dput` (ej `dput(head(iris))`) para que gente sea más fácil tomar tus datos y así ayudarte de forma más rápida!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El paquete [fuzzyjoin](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fuzzyjoin/fuzzyjoin.pdf) sirve para hacer _join_s cuando no se deasea el match exacto, no es necesario reinventar la rueda.

En particular te servir la función `difference_join` la cual tiene argumento de poner la distancia máxima, mira los ejemplos:

```r
library(fuzzyjoin)

df1 <- data.frame(usuarios = c(1, 2, 3, 4), distancias = c(20.005, 21, 23, 19.009))

df2 <- data.frame(usuarios = c(5, 6, 7, 8), distancias = c(20.006, 21, 23, 19.008))


difference_join(df1, df2, by = "distancias", max_dist = 0.001)
#>   usuarios.x distancias.x usuarios.y distancias.y
#> 1          2           21          6           21
#> 2          3           23          7           23



difference_join(df1, df2, by = "distancias", max_dist = 0.1)
#>   usuarios.x distancias.x usuarios.y distancias.y
#> 1          1       20.005          5       20.006
#> 2          2       21.000          6       21.000
#> 3          3       23.000          7       23.000
#> 4          4       19.009          8       19.008



difference_join(df1, df2, by = "distancias", max_dist = Inf)
#>    usuarios.x distancias.x usuarios.y distancias.y
#> 1           1       20.005          5       20.006
#> 2           1       20.005          6       21.000
#> 3           1       20.005          7       23.000
#> 4           1       20.005          8       19.008
#> 5           2       21.000          5       20.006
#> 6           2       21.000          6       21.000
#> 7           2       21.000          7       23.000
#> 8           2       21.000          8       19.008
#> 9           3       23.000          5       20.006
#> 10          3       23.000          6       21.000
#> 11          3       23.000          7       23.000
#> 12          3       23.000          8       19.008
#> 13          4       19.009          5       20.006
#> 14          4       19.009          6       21.000
#> 15          4       19.009          7       23.000
#> 16          4       19.009          8       19.008
```

Comment: ¿Con esta función como se podría indicar que en vez de por una columna "distancias" fuese por dos? He probado con c("distancias", "cantidades") pero me duplica las filas.

Comment: Si entiendo bien tu duda, creo que en ese caso necesitas la función `distance_join`. En caso de no haberla entendido sugiero que actualices la pregunta inicial ;)

Comment: Lo que pretendo es que el join se realice cuando coincidan los datos de dos columnas y no solamente con la de distancia.

Comment: Bueno, yo creo que tendrías que hacer el procedimiento por etapas, primero el join cuando coincida las columnas que tengan que coincidir y luego calcular la diferencia de las distancias de los registros que hicieron match previamente para así filtrar con la distrancia requerida, no?

Comment: Ok, así funciona. Gracias:D

Answer (score 2):

El `merge` no te permite hacer esto, lo que sí se puede, es "alinear" los valores de un dataframe con el del otro y cuando no supere la "tolerancia" lo que hacemos es igualarlos para que entonces el `merge` funcione como queremos. Algo así:

```
usuarios <- c(1,2,3,4)
distancias <- c(20.005,21.000,23.000,19.009)
df1 <- data.frame(usuarios,distancias)

usuarios <- c(5,6,7,8)
distancias <- c(20.006,21.000,23.000,19.008)
df2 <- data.frame(usuarios,distancias)

df1$distancias <- sapply(df1$distancias, function(x)
{
    # El elemento de df1 coincide con tolerancia con el de df2 ?
    ifelse(min(abs(df2$distancias - x), na.rm=TRUE) < 0.001 * x,
           # Si, entonces reemplazo el elemento de df1 por el de df2 para que el merge funcione
           df2[which.min(abs(df2$distancias - x)),"distancias"], 0)
})
df3 <- merge(df1, df2, by = "distancias")
```

El resultado sería algo así:

```
  distancias usuarios.x usuarios.y
1     19.008          4          8
2     20.006          1          5
3     21.000          2          6
4     23.000          3          7
```

Comment: Ok, muchas gracias :D